# Bind the ItemsSource of a DataGrid to a List

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I am trying to create a binding between a `List` and a `DataGrid`. I haven't found a working Solution in the net which is very strange.

In my little example I create a `List` of objects with the two `public` properties `Age` and `Name`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<Person> Collection { get; set; } 

public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    this.Persons = new List<Person>();

    for (int i = 0; i != 35; i++)
    {
        this.Persons.Add(new Person() {Age = i, Name = i.ToString()});
    }

    this.Collection = new ObservableCollection<Person>(this.Persons);
}
```

The XAML Code looks like this:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TestWindow, Path=.}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" />
</Grid>
```

or this (both is not working):

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TestWindow, Path=.}">
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" />
</Grid>
```

if I use `this.DataGrid.ItemsSource = this.Persons;` I see at least all the items in the list but I have to `this.DataGrid.Items.Refresh()` every time the Source `List` changes which is the reason why I ask the question:

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

This question must be very easy to answer but it would be also awesome to understand the mechanics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so the reason why you are having issues is because what happens when the window is loaded and how the data binding is set up.

The ItemsSource of the DataGrid doesn't happen until the Window has already loaded (it's getting set in your Window loaded event). So as a result, the DataGrid does not now that it's ItemsSource has changed. You can fix this by adding INotiftyProperty changed to the list itself, or, you can create the DataGrid list first, and just populate when the Window has loaded.

For example:

xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Collection { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.Persons = new List<Person>();

        for (int i = 0; i != 35; i++)
        {
            this.Persons.Add(new Person() { Age = i, Name = i.ToString() });
        }

        foreach (var p in Persons)
        {
            Collection.Add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        x:Name="TestWindow"
        Loaded="WindowLoaded">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TestWindow, Path=.}">
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This is a cool Solution with a small problem. When you change the Value of e.g. the 3rd element over an button click, then you won't see any changes in the `DataGrid` View. When you scroll down and up again then you will see the change. but not if you don't touch the scrollbar.

Comment: @JensHorstmann right, which is actually a different problem than what you stated. Based on your initial question, you were having a problem w/ displaying items in the DataGrid, but now it looks like you are having a problem displaying updated values from within the items.

Answer (score 2):

After a very long day of coding I was too nervous and tired. the solution is very easy:

Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` `Interface` for the `Person` class:

```
public class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    private int age;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return this.age;
        }
        set
        {
            this.age = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And then bind the Data with these Code behind:

```
this.DataGrid.DataContext = this.Persons;
```

For a successful `Binding` you need also these `XAML` Code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

The valuesin the `DataGrid` will now refresh whenever the Data in one of the `Person` instances changes.

Comment: You do not need to implement INotiftyPropertyChanged. The reason your example works because you are doing a delayed binding and in order for the data context to be updated you need INotifyPropertyChanged. You can do w.out it. ill post an answer below

Comment: You are right. But when i change the value with e.g. a Button Click the view does not change for that i need INotifyPropertyChanged. But i realy would like to see a solution without implementing it! That would be great.

Comment: I added a solution, but based on your last comment maybe I misunderstood your problem.. as it looks like you have another problem other than "Bind the ItemsSource of a DataGrid to a List"

Comment: Well i agree! This was not topic of the thread. i will accept your answer, but maybe we can have a discussion about how i could fix this. Should i now implement INotifyPropertyChanged? or is there a better way?

Comment: If you want to change Person properties during run-time and have it reflect the UI automatically, you will need to implement INotiftyPropertyChangted like you have done (which is the correct approach).

Comment: Yeah, it is working very well. but when i also want to add items to this list i have the next problem.. because then i will get an error the ItemsControl is not linger consistent with the element source... oh god

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88127/discussion-between-d-moncada-and-jens-horstmann).

Answer (score 0):

I do a similar thing a ton in Windows Forms Apps with data grid views. So maybe this can point you in the right direction... I don't have much experience with wpf.

```
List<Connection> connList = new List<Connection>();
//populate list somehow
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = connList;
DataGrid.DataSource = bs;           



    public class Connection
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string Connect {get; set;}

        public Connection(string n, string c)
        {
            Name = n;
            Connect = c;
        }
    }
```